# How can I fully disable FullPage.js under certain conditions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm currently using fullPage.js for an information panel. When the user clicks the info button, a fullPage.js overlay appears on top of the rest of the page. The issue I'm having now is that I don't want the fullPage.js functionality to be applied to the rest of page when the info button isn't active.

Is there a way to fully disable all fullPage.js functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you verified the:  fitToSection or destroy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can destroy it completely by using the [destroy function](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#destroytype):

```
//destroy any plugin event (scrolls, hashchange in the URL...)
$.fn.fullpage.destroy();

//destroy any plugin event and any plugin modification done over your original HTML markup.
$.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
```

Just add that function inside your click event for that button, for example.