# FullPage JS: How to disable it for an unique page?

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I have a problem with FullPage JS, and I come to ask for help :)

My problem is: I want to disable FullPage for a single page of my Website.

FullPage is made for little page, but my website has 1 long page, where I want to disable FullPage.

The file has the .ejs extension, instead of .html extension. The pages are in different EJS file.

I searched on the FullPage's Github, and it indicates me the `destroy('all')` method, but I've found a lot of way to write it, I tried 3 methods, and I don't know why, it doesn't work.

Does any of you know how to disable FullPage JS on a single page of the Website ?

I tried 3 methods.

1st Method tried:

```
document.querySelector('#destroy').addEventListener('click', function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault(); 
   fullpage_api.destroy('all'); 
});
```

2nd Method:

```
$('#destroy').click(function () { 
  $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all'); 
});
```

3rd Method:

```
function DestroyFullPage() { //default is 700. 
  $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all'); 
}
```

As Alvaro suggested, I  tried something like this:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        alert('Ready ?');
        fullpage_api.destroy('all');
        alert('Done');
    }
</script>
```

The first alert works fine, but the second never appear on my screen, and FullPage isn't destroyed.

Am I wrong in my syntax ?

Thanks

PS: Excuse my English, I'm french, but at least, I try :D

Comment: can't you just not include it on that page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fully disable FullPage.js under certain conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374656/how-can-i-fully-disable-fullpage-js-under-certain-conditions)

Comment: Hello @ADyson, maybe I'm dumb, but i didn't understand :/


Hi @RonS,  I tried this function, but I don't have a JS function on that specific button, it's an `href` done in html, and adding an id to add JS on it, doesn't work. Btw, the files are like `index.ejs` instead of `index.html` :)

Comment: if you have a different page, by this do you mean a different HTML file, or do you mean you actually have a single-page application and a "page" is just a logical thing within it where you change the data on display? If you have a separate actual HTML document for your long page, then I meant that on that HTML page you would simply not include the `<script` tag for fullPage.js. However if everything is actually in one big HTML document then clearly that won't work. From your question it's not really clear what your setup is like.

Comment: Anyway, you said you tried this "destroy" method without success...but you didn't show us what you tried. Perhaps we can correct it for you. Did you get any console errors when you tried to use it?

Comment: @ADyson, wow, you are quick !

Well, i tried 3 methods. As I said, the files has the `.ejs` extension, instead of `.html` extension. The pages are in different EJS file.

1st Method tried: ```document.querySelector('#destroy').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  fullpage_api.destroy('all');
 });```

2nd Method: ```$('#destroy').click(function () {
    $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
});```

3rd Method: ```function DestroyFullPage() {
        //default is 700. 
        $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
    }```

Comment: None of these works. I took them from the owner of FullPage repository on Github: Alvaro  Trigo, and I had no console errors on it

Comment: I added your code into the question so it's readable and clear. Comments are not the place for code. Anyway, when you say they don't work...do you get any console errors when you try to run them? or does anything else strange happen? Does your page include jQuery?

Comment: Oh, thanks for edition. Well, nothing strange happened, and no console error, so I thought that the JS didn't work, but when i make a `console.log("Hello")`, I can see it for 1 second, just the time for the page to reload the console. And yes, I tried to include jQuery in my page

Comment: it sounds like something is making your page refresh. I doubt it's this code though.

Comment: I dunno ... :/ Is there another way to disable fullpage than `destroy` ?

Comment: Up ? I know I'm a bit pressed, but it's for a website that needs to be online asap ... :/

Answer (score 0):

If you wonder how to use the destroy function, you can check the demo provided on the fullPage.js docs:
https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/bdxBzv

Which basically uses fullpage.js version 3 (no jQuery required) to do so:

```
fullpage_api.destroy('all');
```

There's no difference at all between your 2nd method and the 3rd one. In fact, 3rd method won't work until you call the `DestroyFullPage` somewhere else.

And the 1st one should only be used when initialising fullPage.js with jQuery. So, using `$('#fullpage').fullpage(options)` instead of `new fullpage('#fullpage', options);`

Comment: Hello Alvaro, thanks for your answer, but still don't work (cf post). :)

Comment: Then you'll have to wonder why. Because the destroy functions works :)